# Get DocumentPart from OpenXmlElement when working with Word document in OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm modifying a docx template with OpenXML API and run into a problem.

I need to insert an image into a certain place - that place is defined by a Content Controll element that can be in the main part of document, header of footer.

I'm getting content controll like this:

```
static IEnumerable<TElement> GetDecendants<TElement>(OpenXmlPart part) where TElement : OpenXmlElement
{
    var result = part.RootElement
        .Descendants()
        .OfType<TElement>();

    return result;
}
```

Later down the pipeline I need to insert an image to the correct part of the document via this

```
internal static OpenXmlElement InsertImage(OpenXmlPart documentPart, Stream stream, string fileName, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
{
    // actual implementation that is tested and works
}
```

Now my problem is that when I discover a ContentControl element that needs to be replaced by an image, I don't have a reference to `documentPart` - I only have reference so `SdtRun` or `SdtBlock`.

Is there a way to navigate to `documentPart` from `SdtRun`? I've checked `.Parent` but could not find a way to go from `OpenXmlElement` to `OpenXmlPart` - these are in different hierarchies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend the below method.  It uses [Ancestor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc822192(v=office.15).aspx) to avoid [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) and takes advantage of the short-circuiting [Null-conditional Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) from C# 6.

```
    internal static OpenXmlPart GetMainDocumentPart(OpenXmlElement xmlElement)
    {
        return
        xmlElement?.Ancestors<Document>()?.FirstOrDefault()?.MainDocumentPart as OpenXmlPart ??
        xmlElement?.Ancestors<Footer>()?.FirstOrDefault()?.FooterPart as OpenXmlPart ??
        xmlElement?.Ancestors<Header>()?.FirstOrDefault()?.HeaderPart as OpenXmlPart;
    }
```

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of question marks! I'll check it out when back to work. Thanks!

Comment: This generally works. But fails when `xmlElement` is a `Header` or a `Document` or  a `Footer` - it does not have ancestors of the same types. However, the general idea and pointing me towards `Ancestors<>()` (method which I did not know about before) is good

Comment: Actually a  `Header`, `Footer` and `Document` are each `OpenXmlPart` and are not `OpenXmlElement`, so calling this method with them wont even compile, much less run.  I think this method should hold up for you.

Comment: But my code below compiles and `Header`, `Footer` and `Document` are all `OpenXmlElement` not parts. Can't find the source code on GitHub anywhere, but I've seen it decompiled.

Comment: You are correct.  Your code does compile.  I was incorrect in my last comment - they are indeed `OpenXmlElement`s -

Answer (score 1):

Having gone through the source code of OpenXML I have found a method that did what I needed. Only it was marked `internal` and I could not use it in my code.

So I came up with this:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System;


internal static class XmlElementHelpers
{
    internal static OpenXmlPart GetDocumentPart(this OpenXmlElement xmlElement)
    {
        if (xmlElement == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (xmlElement is Document document)
        {
            return document.MainDocumentPart;
        }

        if (xmlElement is Header header)
        {
            return header.HeaderPart;
        }

        if (xmlElement is Footer footer)
        {
            return footer.FooterPart;
        }

        return GetDocumentPart(xmlElement.Parent);
    }
}
```